# Angular Smarttable is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using smart table for my project. I cannot make it works, not sure what happen.

When i added `st-table` directive to `<table>` the result will not displayed in table, however it will display the result in table if i remove `st-table` directive from `<table>` but it will give an error in console because the `st-table` directive is needed by `st-pagination`.

Here the code

**HTML**

```
<table st-table="Tablelist" class="table table-stripped">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="selectedAll()" />
    </th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in Tablelist track by $index">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.selected">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="Opensetprice(x.id,x.matcode,x.pr_qty)">$</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="Delete(x.doc_no,x.item_no, $index)">X</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>{{x.date}}</td>
    <td>{{x.type}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="23" class="text-center">
        <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="12" st-displayed-pages="5"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "api/all-list.php",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
  }).then(function(response) {
    $scope.Tablelist = response.data;
  }, function(response) {
    console.log("failed");
})
```

Comment: Read the instructions for ajax loaded data set up

Answer (score 0):

You have not implemented st-pipe="callServer". You have to handle all get calls from server using this function if you want to you st-table

Comment: That's the only way if all you are doing is loading table once there is also alternate approach

Comment: You can try alternate approach but then using smarttable and its feature without callserver function (which comes with built in pagination and search params, st-search, st-sort and a lot more features becomes null and void). There is no point of using st-table if you need alternate approach. You can just write $http get method and bind using ng-repeat